# An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I followed this [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html)
to add doctrine to my symfony project(v4.2). But when doctrine is installed it deosn't add this line to my project ( in my .env file like mentioned in the doc ):

> DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name"

So I added it manually like this :

> DATABASE_URL="mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/db_school"

and used this commande to create the database :

> php bin/console doctrine:database:create

and it gives me this error :

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:
>                                                                                                                                 An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 31:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>   In PDOConnection.php line 27:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Even I changed the user and password it still dosn't recognize it . Any idea why it dosn't work ? I will appreciate it .

Comment: Do you have `.env.local` file which may override this variable?

Comment: No Sir . I don't have it .

Comment: The error message is inconsistent with the config line you add !
I think that's a bad thing to use root. Create an user and grant him with "administration rights".
Do you have a database named "db_school" in your DBMS ?
Do you have an user named "db_user" in your DBMS ?

Comment: No Sir ! I dont have them. I just have the root as user name .and database dosnt exist

Comment: your root username have a password ? if yes then try :

 DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:yourPassword@127.0.0.1:3306/db_school" 
 and  php bin/console doctrine:database:create

Comment: No sir it doesnt have a password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method seem to not work for me I dont kniw why but it worked this way :

- So I used Flex to install doctrine :

> composer require doctrine

Then I run this :

> composer require orm

- then I went to my file `.env` and I found my database syntax generated automaticlyy and everything worked fine .
- Also I deleted the other sql processors that were open on my computer ( i hv installed sql server too + wamp which explaine the conflict that I have) and then re-opened my wamp server and everything is working fine.

Comment: you did not solve it, you don't even understand why the error exist. instead you installed a bunch of "$(/%)"($/ and that fixed it for you. The answeres above are 100% correct you just forgot the " : " symbol for empty password. Did you just want to answere your own question?

Comment: That's a bold statement

Answer (score 6):

I think you have to create an user "db_user" with password in your DBMS. Then grant him with "Administration" rights. Then correct .env's database configuration line :

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name"
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but I still have the same probleme :

Comment: Search the string "db_user" in all project's files and check if it exists only where it has to exists

Comment: I searched but it doesn't exist . I don't know where the problem come from

Answer (score 3):

Try using the same syntax like you have a password, just enter nothing where password suppose to be:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/db_school"
```

As it's explained here: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/746#issuecomment-351788298

Answer (score 0):

For me all the configurations were right. I found that this error was happening because of the service "MySQL 80" wasn't running, to fix that:

1. Press the "Windows" button and search for "services"
   [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqhjf.png)
2. Stop the service "MySQL" [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCONu.png)
3. Start the service "MySQL 80" [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuCY1.png)

Now try again and the problem should be solved

Answer (score 0):

Also pay attention that the password shouldnt contain special characters, or it should be encoded. See:

"If the username, password, host or database name contain any character considered special in a URI (such as +, @, $, #, /, :, *, !, %), you must encode them. See RFC 3986 for the full list of reserved characters or use the urlencode function to encode them. In this case you need to remove the resolve: prefix in config/packages/doctrine.yaml to avoid errors: url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'"