# doctrine:database:create connection refused

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, doctrine

I have `bitnami LAMPStack 7.4.6-1` running `MySQL` database on `3307 port` on newest Ubuntu. Symfony version 5.1.0
When I run this command as root user:

```
root@ubuntu:/opt/lampstack-7.4.6-1/apache2/htdocs/sfcourse# php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

the error I'm seeing is:

```
[error] Error thrown while running command "doctrine:database:create". Message: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused"


In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:

  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  


In PDOConnection.php line 31:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  


In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

.env file `DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:000000@localhost:3307/sfcourse`

EDITED: doctrine.yaml file:

```
doctrine:
#    parameters:
#        env(DATABASE_URL): ''
    dbal:
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

googled but most suggestions are to make 127.0.0.1 as localhost

EDIT:
MySQL version is 8.0.20 after checking `mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`

I can login to SQL via terminal as root, that is working

EDIT: I created same way user test, can login via terminal to MySQL, but cannot create database via doctrine. We are at the same beginning.

EDIT: I changed sql port back to default 3306 and running as sudo doctrine command. Error now:

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for u  
  ser 'db_user'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

I can connect as db_user to MySQL. If I change user in .env to other, error still says db_user.

EDIT: this is same question [An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687722/an-exception-occurred-in-driver-sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user) but answer is dumb, he installed what he had.

Comment: What version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: The errors suggest that your user (root in this case) does not have access to mysql. Try manually logging into mysql via terminal. If you cannot, that's your problem. If you can, give your user (not root) full access to mysql and change your `DATABASE_URL`

Comment: symfony 5.1.0 (env: dev, debug: true)

I can login via terminal as root to sql, but not via doctrine

Comment: Did you try adding yourself to the mysql group and use root to give yourself full access (all privileges)?

Comment: i see mysql root user exists, to which group should i add root user?

Comment: Not root user. The user you are using (or create a new user within mysql). Check [this](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-grant-all-privileges-on-a-database-in-mysql/) article.

Comment: I created new fresh user, granted all privileges, but access denied when connecting via terminal : ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'foo'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
A bit confused. Root user is able to login via terminal.

Comment: Two more things I can think of you to try: First add user `foo` to group `mysql` - `usermod -a -G mysql foo`. If that doesn't work as a last resort try running the doctrine command with `sudo`. The latter should not be used, ever, but to test where the problem is just this once.

Comment: Actually one more thing - I just noticed that you are using port 3307. By default 3306 is used. Also in all my projects I use 127.0.0.1, not localhost in the url. Try changing it to `DATABASE_URL=mysql://foo:password@127.0.0.1:3306/sfcourse`

Comment: I'm running as sudo, changed sql port back to 3306, but the configuration is using some other user. See update.

Comment: As a last resort try downgrading your mysql to version 5.7.

Comment: I installed everything as lampstack, this is not a qualified solution

Answer (score -1):

In your doctrine.yaml file remove these lines

```
    parameters:
        env(DATABASE_URL): ''
```

According to the current [symonfy documentation for doctrine](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) there is no `parameters` in the doctrine.yaml file.

The `server_version` caused some headaches for me. I fixed it with this line

```
server_version: 5.7.9
```

To find out your server version [source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.0-en/installation-version.html)

Connect to your database via console, it will state you the version right away

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 6
Server version: 5.0.27-standard MySQL Community Edition - Standard (GPL)
```

or else

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                                    |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| protocol_version        | 10                                       |
| version                 | 5.0.27-standard                          |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Edition - Standard (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | i686                                     |
| version_compile_os      | pc-linux-gnu                             |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Comment: actually I added
 parameters:
        env(DATABASE_URL): ''
by myself trying various options, it was not by default.