# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'symfony'@'localhost' (using password: YES) ----- docker

Tags: mysql, docker, symfony

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaPZd.png)

error:

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:

An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'symfony'@'localhost' (usin
g password: YES)

In Exception.php line 18:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'symfony'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

In PDOConnection.php line 38:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'symfony'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

.env : DATABASE_URL=mysql://symfony:symfony@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony?serverVersion=5.7

docker setup: docker-compose.yml

```
 db:
        container_name: db
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        command: ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: symfony
            MYSQL_USER: symfony
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: symfony
            DATABASE_URL: symfony.localhost
        networks:
            - db
```

Comment: hi, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687722/an-exception-occurred-in-driver-sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string should be:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://symfony:symfony@db/symfony?serverVersion=5.7
```

Tl;dr use `db` not `localhost` / `127.0.0.1` for the host part. The `db` is the name of the container with MySQL. Docker containers behave like hosts to themselves.

If you don't intend to connect to the MySQL from your host (eg. using MySQL workbench / Sequel Pro) you can drop the `ports: 3306:3306` publishing part in the `docker-compose` file. It's not needed for the port to work. Containers are allowed to talk to themselves freely within their network to any port.